# Kubuntu 9.10: LUKS-encrypt entire partition

Tags: ubuntu, kubuntu, luks

In older versions of Ubuntu, mainly 8.04, I could encrypt en entire partition using [`LUKS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup), and mount it as `/.` the `/boot` directory was mounted on another partition.

At boot time, I had to enter my password to enable any access to anything other than `/boot`.

In Kubuntu 9.10, I only have the option to encrypt my `/home/adam` directory, which is a bit of a problem for me because I have sensitive data located in other directories.

Any ideas how to set up `LUKS` for the entire disk, preferably during installation?

Thanks in advance,

Adam

Answer (score 0):

Does this short discussion on [Luks Encryption](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1138774) help you?

Update: [7 Steps To An Encrypted Partition](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2007/08/17/7-steps-to-an-encrypted-partition-local-or-removable-disk/)

> how to encrypt a local partition or a removable device (like a USB key). The steps used here will work for either type of device although you’ll need to replace your partition name and number for the examples provided here.

Comment: Not completely - How do I practically create the encrypted volume? Using a live CD? If so, How do I install Kubuntu later? Does it recognize the LUKS partition during installation?